# How come "median" is 2x faster than "mean" using statistics package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics

This surprises me... To illustrate I've used this small code to calculate mean and median of 1M random numbers:

```
import numpy as np
import statistics as st

import time

listofrandnum = np.random.rand(1000000,)

t = time.time()
print('mean is:', st.mean(listofrandnum))
print('time to calc mean:', time.time()-t)

print('\n')

t = time.time()
print('median is:', st.median(listofrandnum))
print('time to calc median:', time.time()-t)
```

For which the result is:

```
mean is: 0.499866595037
time to calc mean: 2.0767598152160645


median is: 0.499721597395
time to calc median: 0.9687695503234863
```

My question: How come mean is slower than median? median needs some sorting algorithm (i.e. comparisons) while mean requires summing. Does it make sense that a sum will be slower than comparison?

I will appreciate your insight into this.

Comment: FYI, there is no need to sort the entire array to find the median. You can use quickselect to do that in O(n) on the average.

Comment: I removed `numpy` from the title because this question is about the `statistics` module, not `numpy` performance.  I'll leave it in the tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`statistics` isn't part of NumPy. It's a Python standard library module with a rather different design philosophy; it goes for accuracy at all costs, even for unusual input datatypes and extremely poorly-conditioned input. Performing a sum the way the `statistics` module does it is *really* expensive, more so than performing a sort.

If you want an efficient mean or median on NumPy arrays, use the NumPy routines:

```
numpy.mean(whatever)
numpy.median(whatever)
```

If you want to see the expensive work the `statistics` module goes through for a simple sum, you can look at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py):

```
def _sum(data, start=0):
    """_sum(data [, start]) -> (type, sum, count)

    Return a high-precision sum of the given numeric data as a fraction,
    together with the type to be converted to and the count of items.

    If optional argument ``start`` is given, it is added to the total.
    If ``data`` is empty, ``start`` (defaulting to 0) is returned.


    Examples
    --------

    >>> _sum([3, 2.25, 4.5, -0.5, 1.0], 0.75)
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(11, 1), 5)

    Some sources of round-off error will be avoided:

    >>> _sum([1e50, 1, -1e50] * 1000)  # Built-in sum returns zero.
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(1000, 1), 3000)

    Fractions and Decimals are also supported:

    >>> from fractions import Fraction as F
    >>> _sum([F(2, 3), F(7, 5), F(1, 4), F(5, 6)])
    (<class 'fractions.Fraction'>, Fraction(63, 20), 4)

    >>> from decimal import Decimal as D
    >>> data = [D("0.1375"), D("0.2108"), D("0.3061"), D("0.0419")]
    >>> _sum(data)
    (<class 'decimal.Decimal'>, Fraction(6963, 10000), 4)

    Mixed types are currently treated as an error, except that int is
    allowed.
    """
    count = 0
    n, d = _exact_ratio(start)
    partials = {d: n}
    partials_get = partials.get
    T = _coerce(int, type(start))
    for typ, values in groupby(data, type):
        T = _coerce(T, typ)  # or raise TypeError
        for n,d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
            count += 1
            partials[d] = partials_get(d, 0) + n
    if None in partials:
        # The sum will be a NAN or INF. We can ignore all the finite
        # partials, and just look at this special one.
        total = partials[None]
        assert not _isfinite(total)
    else:
        # Sum all the partial sums using builtin sum.
        # FIXME is this faster if we sum them in order of the denominator?
        total = sum(Fraction(n, d) for d, n in sorted(partials.items()))
    return (T, total, count)
```

Comment: Using the numpy methods, it takes my computer about 2 ms for the mean and 16 ms for the median.